# How to install Angular CLI manually without using npm install

Tags: node.js, angular, eclipse, npm, angular-cli

Since my company has some proxy that prevents downloading from external websites, I'm unable to use `npm install` to download Angular cli.

I found some resources to do it behind Corporate Proxy Server, but it needs admin which I don't have access.

Is there any way that I can download the package and install manually?

Thanks.

I found Angular Cli [github page](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli).

I expect to use Angular Cli on local environment.

Comment: Unless you want to spend your entire **week** finding, downloading and manually installing each dependency one by one. You will need to either configure a corporate proxy, get the firewall rules updated or find a new job.

Comment: You should be able to just copy the files into node_modules.  As far as I recall the Angular packages have no or few dependencies.

Comment: Convince them or leave

Comment: What is the error you are getting ? how are you sure your proxy server is not letting you do npm install ?

Comment: You have to configure some proxy settings, [**check this article this will guide you how to set up proxy in a corporate environment**](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-npm-install-the-command-behind-corporate-proxy-server/), specially step 4 and step 5 ..hope this is helpful!

Comment: Ones you set up the proxy, you can [**set npm registry**](https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-your-registry-settings-as-an-npm-enterprise-user) and then you can `npm install @angular/cli -g` as usual

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure npm to use your company's proxy

```
npm config set http-proxy http://<username>:<password>@[proxy-server-host-name]:[Port]
npm config set https-proxy https://<username>:<password>@[proxy-server-host-name]:[Port]
```

for example

```
npm config set http-proxy http://testuser:testpassword@proxy.testserver.com:9091
npm config set https-proxy https://testuser:testpassword@proxy.testserver.com:9091
```

Comment: how can I find my company's proxy